# How to Load AsyncStorage Data on App Load and set to context in Expo?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, expo

I created an Expo project and I am setting some data to LocalStorage using AsyncStorage.
I want to reload that data on App start and want to assign that data to context/State.
How I can achieve that any one can help me to solve this problem.

here is my code of app.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { Asset } from 'expo-asset';
import * as Font from 'expo-font';
import { AppLoading } from 'expo';
....

const client = new ApolloClient({
  // link: new HttpLink({
  uri:'',
  request: (operation) => {
    getToken().then(token=>{
      console.log('APIToken:', token);
      operation.setContext({
        headers: {
          'api-token': token ? `${token}` : ''
        }
      })
    }); 
  },
  //}),
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  });


const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: '#fffef9',
  },
});

export default class App extends React.Component {


  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.updateContext=(key, value)=>{
      this.setState({
        [key]: value
      });
    };

    this.updateStack=(stack)=>{
      this.setState({
        activeStack: stack
      });
    };

    this.loadUsers=(users, _activeUser)=>{
      console.log('Users:', users);
      this.setState({
        users: users,
        activeUser: _activeUser
      });
    };

    this.logOutUser=()=>{
      this.setState({
        activeUser: {},
        users:[],
        activeStack:'Auth'
      });
    };


    this.state = {
      isReady: false,
      activeUser:{},
      users: [],
      activeStack:'Auth',
      updateStack: this.updateStack,
      updateContext: this.updateContext,
      loadUsers: this.loadUsers,
      logOutUser: this.logOutUser
    };
  }

  render() {
    if (!this.state.isReady) {
      return (
        <AppLoading
          startAsync={this._cacheResourcesAsync}
          onFinish={(res) => {this.setState({ isReady: true })}}
          onError={console.warn}
        />
      ); }

    return (
          <ApolloProvider client={client}>
            <SafeAreaProvider>
              <SafeAreaView forceInset={{ bottom: 115 }} style={styles.container}>
                {Platform.OS === 'ios' && <StatusBar barStyle="default" />}
                  <AppContext.Provider value={this.state}>
                    <AppNavigator/>
                  </AppContext.Provider>
              </SafeAreaView>
            </SafeAreaProvider>
          </ApolloProvider>
    );
  }

  async _cacheResourcesAsync() {
    await Promise.all([
    Asset.loadAsync([
      //      require('./assets/images/robot-dev.png'),
    ]),
    Font.loadAsync({
      'body': require('./assets/fonts/Archivo-Regular.ttf'),
      'body-bold': require('./assets/fonts/Archivo-SemiBold.ttf'),
      'headline': require('./assets/fonts/Nunito-Medium.ttf'),
      'headline-bold': require('./assets/fonts/Nunito-Bold.ttf'),
      'headline-extra-bold': require('./assets/fonts/Nunito-ExtraBold.ttf'),
    })
  ]);
  }
}
```

I have a function to loaduser() in a separate file, where i am loading users from localstorage and returning a promise. You can tell me where i should call loadUser() and handle its promise to loadState.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. My solution was create another Component.
My App.js:

```
export default () => {
  const [isReady, setIsReady] = useState(false);

  const loadAssetsAsync = async () => {
    const imageAssets = cacheImages([
      require('./assets/images/bg_screen1.jpg'),
      require('./assets/images/bg_screen2.jpg'),
      require('./assets/images/bg_screen3.jpg'),
      require('./assets/images/bg_screen4.jpg'),
      require('./assets/images/user-cool.png'),
      require('./assets/images/user-hp.png'),
      require('./assets/images/user-student.png'),
      require('./assets/images/avatar1.jpg'),
    ]);

    const fontAssets = cacheFonts([
      ...vectorFonts,
      { georgia: require('./assets/fonts/Georgia.ttf') },
      { regular: require('./assets/fonts/Montserrat-Regular.ttf') },
      { light: require('./assets/fonts/Montserrat-Light.ttf') },
      { bold: require('./assets/fonts/Montserrat-Bold.ttf') },
      { UbuntuLight: require('./assets/fonts/Ubuntu-Light.ttf') },
      { UbuntuBold: require('./assets/fonts/Ubuntu-Bold.ttf') },
      { UbuntuLightItalic: require('./assets/fonts/Ubuntu-Light-Italic.ttf') },
    ]);

    await Promise.all([...imageAssets, ...fontAssets]);
  };

  if (!isReady) {
    return (
      <AppLoading
        startAsync={loadAssetsAsync}
        onFinish={() => setIsReady(true)}
        onError={console.warn}
      />
    );
  }

  return <RootNavigator />;
};
```

My RootNavigator:

```
export default () => {
const [loaded, setLoaded] = useState(false);
const [init, setInit] = useState(false);
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchData = async () => {

    const type = await getUserType()
    const name = await getName()
    const UID = await getUID()
    const token = await getToken()

    if (!type || !name || !UID || !token) {
      inital = 'Login'
    } else if (type === 'CLIENT') {
      inital = 'Client'
    } else if (type === 'EMPLOYEEE') {
      inital = 'Employee'
    }
    setInit(inital)

  }
  fetchData()
}, [])

function returnRoute() {
  AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
    Login: {
      screen: LoginScreen,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerShown: false
      }
    },
    Client: {
      screen: DrawerNavigator,
      navigationOptions: {
        headerShown: false,
      },
    },
    StoreBooking: StoreBookingScreen,
    StoreContract: StoreContractScreen,
    IndexContracts: IndexContractsScreen,
    ShowActivity: ShowActivityScreen,
    ShowUniqueBooking: ShowUniqueBookingScreen,
    Addresses: ShowAddressesScreen,
  },
    {
      initialRouteName: init,
      defaultNavigationOptions: {
        headerStyle: {
          backgroundColor: cli.Client.b1,
        },
        headerTintColor: '#fff',
        headerTitleStyle: {
          fontWeight: 'bold',
        },

      }
    })

  RootNavigator = createAppContainer(AppNavigator);
  return <RootNavigator />

}
return (

  loaded && init ? (
    <Awaiter />
  )
    :
    returnRoute()
)
```

}